# Epson Workforce 845 scanner functions?

Tags: scanner

Just successfully installed an Epson Workforce 845 printer-FAX-scanner.  Printer works OK, but there don't seem to be any drivers etc. for the scanner function(s).  Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for these drivers:

[Epson Workforce 845](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escp/) scroll about 1/3 of the way down on the page

[image]

Scanner Drivers [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

[image]

According to the [SANE web site](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-backends-external.html)

`>>>>> found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0892) at libusb:001:007 is your Epson scanner.`

Time to edit: `gksudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` Example Snippet follows:

```
# epkowa.conf -- sample configuration for the EPKOWA SANE backend
# Copyright (C) 2004, 2008, 2009  Olaf Meeuwissen
#
# See sane-epkowa(5), sane-usb(5) and sane-scsi(5) for details.

# Detect all devices supported by the backend.
# If you don't have a SCSI device, you can comment out the "scsi"
# keyword.  Similarly for the other keywords.
#
usb
scsi


# For any USB scanner not known to the backend (yet), you may, at your
# own peril(!!), force the backend to recognise and use it via libusb.
# You can do so by the following configuration command:
# 
#   usb <USB vendor ID> <USB product ID>
#
# SEIKO EPSON's USB vendor ID is '0x04b8' (without quotes).  In order
# to find the USB product ID, use lsusb(1).
# A sample configuration for the Epson Perfection 1650 (Epson GT-8200),
# which has a product ID of 0x0110, would look as follows:
#
#usb 0x04b8 0x0110
```

you will need to insert (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0892) per the example and remove the "#" at the beginning code line. Save and reboot.

Comment: These are CUPS drivers for the printer functions.  As stated in the original post, the printer drivers install successfully from the CD supplied by Epson.  It's the SANE driver(s) that appear to be missing.

Comment: as listed they were for workforce 845 MFP, will look for 
Epson Avasys Image Scan!

Comment: Look at this please http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult 3rd blue box down on the rignt

Comment: Thanks, this is getting closer, but still no cigar.  The scanner is recognized (by Simple Scan), but only produces an error message: "Failed to Scan.  Unable to connect to scanner."  The cable is OK (I can print), but the printer won't scan to PC ("no connection") either.

Comment: The thing I have with enabled with my Epson CX8400 is the SANE packages, like libsane and xsane. From here to nowhere, gave it a shot.

Comment: Installed the SANE packages.  They recognize my HP Photosmart (all three modes: scan, FAX and print), but not the Epson Workforce 845 - not at all.  I wonder if there is a problem in the WF-845's scanner interface hardware and/or software.  I'm going to try installing the i386 versions of iscan to see if that works -- there could be a word/byte alignment problem in the 64-bit version.

Comment: The i386 versions won't install ("wrong architecture") even though x86/386 programs are supposed to run seamlessly on AMD-64 (mine is an Athlon).

Comment: run "sane-find-scanner -q" receive an output something like =
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0839) at libusb:001:004

Comment: Finds two scanners.  The first is identified only by the vendor code, the second is identified as an HP Photosmart:  found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8, product=0x0892) at libusb:001:007
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [HP], product=0x5a11 [Photosmart C7100 series]) at libusb:001:006
I tried installing the Workforce 845 on my HP Pavilion (Windows 7).  The scanner and FAX installed and the scanner works, but printer installation has never completed (48 minutes elapsed so far).

Comment: I have found information on Avasys' site and downloaded the correct driver (iscan-2.28-1.3.ltdl7_amd64.deb), which is about 12K larger than the same-named file on Epson's site.  It works with the data file (iscan-data_1.14-1_all.deb) from Epson.  The ltdl7 version is for Ubuntu releases 8.10 and later.  Thank you very much, BlueXrider, for you assistance.